# Separate left and right mouse clicks when clicking on canvas

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I want to call some functions when I click left and right on the canvas. I wrote the following code for this:

```
mpMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();
mpClickPoint = new QgsMapToolEmitPoint(mpMapCanvas);
connect(mpClickPoint, SIGNAL(canvasClicked(QgsPointXY,Qt::MouseButton)), this, SLOT(selectCoord(QgsPointXY)));
```

This code works, but for both left and right mouse click. So there is no difference between them right now. Either left or right click is calling selectCoord() function.
I want to separate them and make it work only when I click left. That's why I tried:

```
connect(mpClickPoint, SIGNAL(canvasPressEvent(QgsMapMouseEvent)), this, SLOT(mouseEvent(QgsMapMouseEvent)));
void MainWindow::mouseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton){
        qDebug() << "Left clicked" << '\n';
    }
}
```

I don't know why it didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with the following change:

```
connect(mpClickPoint, SIGNAL(canvasClicked(QgsPointXY,Qt::MouseButton)), this, SLOT(mouseEvent(QgsPointXY,Qt::MouseButton)));
    
void MainWindow::mouseEvent(QgsPointXY point, Qt::MouseButton button){
        if (button == Qt::LeftButton){
            // do some stuff
        }
}
```